# travel and expenses ax 2012 UK Credit Cards

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012, erp, ax

Im looking at the Travel and Expense Management module in AX2012 and i was wondering if anyone has managed to get the import feature working for UK credit cards? My Senior Consultant has said that this feature will only work for American cards but I imagine that with some dev work it would be possible to enable other formats also.

If anyone has any info or idea's that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a [.NET transform assembly](http://technet.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/gg863930.aspx) that would be transforming text files e.g. in CSV format into XML used to populate the `TrvPBSMainData` table. You can find a sample Visual Studio project along with step by step instructions in the [Microsoft Dynamics AX Solution Architecture team blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/axsa/archive/2013/01/08/importing-credit-card-statements-into-dynamics-ax-2012-using-aif-and-transformation-library.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. 
I've heard that british banks dont use L3 data and thus largely invalidate the point of importing statements? Is this true, or is there any comparable data that can be used?

Comment: As I understand, our client has negotiated the format of the statement (CSV file) with the Royal Bank of Scotland. I guess it all depends on how important the client is to the bank.